# Bayesian information criterion from measure theoretic point of view?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference

Bayesian information criterion (BIC) is well known and it is derived from the maximizing the posterior density function which is equivalent to solving the marginal likelihood integral. My question is: Is there any measure theoretic analysis of BIC?